# Creating a image file format only my site can read

Tags: php, image

I'm considering writing my own image file format for my site. Why? Well, the site is going to include comics that only subscribers can read, and I want to make it a little difficult for someone to drag and drop the image and spread it around. Is there a better way of doing this, or is this a way I should investigate further? If so, how would one go about doing this?

I've read there could be a way in PHP with doing this, but unsure how to go about it if this is a good solution.

Comment: Could people not just take a screenshot and upload it?

Comment: That is true, they can, however, I don't want them to grab the original photo. You know, now that I think about it, there really is no deterrent from this type of thing.

Comment: Well you could add there watermark of your site if you really want.. and yea.. you cannot prevent screenshooting

Comment: I think the biggest thing is that they can't drag and drop it at the least. As long as that's not there, I don't really mind if they screen cap it.

Comment: Interesting question.  It sounds similar to the challenge that the music industry faces in trying to protect digital music from being copied.  Despite all of their attempts, there is always the 'analog hole', whereby the protected music can easily be copied to an unprotected format simply by playing the protected music file out of the audio output of one device, and into the audio input of another device to record it in an unprotected format.

Comment: I would suggest to have a function using the GD library, that will add a watermark over top every image in a given folder. If they want to see the full image without it (watermark), they would need to be a registered and validated/confirmed user. That's just how "I" would do it.

Comment: If it can be displayed in an HTML page it has to be a valid image format (JPEG, PNG, GIF, etc). Adopting a different format will not change that. Your other options would be to display the image differently, say using Flash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's impossible to completely prevent your images from being stolen, but you can make the process *harder*.

The following method will make the real image unreachable unless checked from the source. You can use the original image as a background & put a transparent-blank file over it that matches the size of the real image.

Example:

```
<div id="image1" style="background-image: url(originalImage.jpg);">
    <img src="blank.gif" height="250px" width="300px">
</div>
```

So, when the image is right-clicked, it will be the `blank.gif` that can be reached.

View [this](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/10-ways-to-protect-images-from-being-stolen/) post for some other ideas.

An alternative solution would be to use PHP's [GD Library](http://www.sitepoint.com/watermark-images-php/). Using this method, you can add a watermark on all your images.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Something I was considering is using HTML5 canvas to display the image.

I know it is impossible to prevent an image from being copied, but truth be told, if someone is trying really hard to copy it, that means they loved it very much which also means we are doing a good job :)

Comment: See this [page](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-images/). HTML5 requires javascript and you'd still need to refer to a valid image file. The alternative would be to use Flash.

Comment: Regarding *"The following method will make the real image unreachable..."*, are you referring to `originalImage.jpg` being the image that is **not** to be copied, the **"protected"** file?

Comment: @Fred: yes, that's what I meant. :)

Comment: @AmalMurali Well then **"unreachable"** shouldn't have been the word to use, because anyone could view the source and pull the file name from it and paste it in their address bar. I would say use the words **"hard to get"**. (wink)